# Change in the values of parameters - web2py application

Tags: python, web2py

I am new to web2py and trying out an application. Please see below for the relevant `controller` functions and the corresponding relevant `views`. I start by pointing my browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/default/index` after which I follow the application. I experience, what appears strange to me: sometimes (not always, about once in 5-6 times) the values of MC and maxWTP displayed on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/default/inandout` page change **after** the first time the price is entered. What I am trying to do is that MC and maxWTP should be chosen randomly when one goes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/default/index`, and these are used to create a marketobject; but not after that. Once the page has been redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/default/inandout` I do not see why MC and maxWTP should change after price is entered. Also, it appears to happen only after the first time the price is entered. Can someone please explain to me why this might be happening and how to correct that? 
I am using the Chrome browser and Version 1.99.7 (2012-03-04 22:12:08) of web2py and python 2.7.

I do not think the reason lies in market module. But if you want to see the market module and other modules it depends on please let me know.

**Controller functions**

```
import random
import market


def index():
    '''Creates a new market object and resets the price, quantity
    and profit histories'''
    session.marketobject = None
    mc = random.choice([1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2])
    maxWTP = random.choice([4,5,6,7])
    session.marketobject = market.Market(mc,maxWTP)
    session.priceHistory = []
    session.profitHistory = []
    session.quantityHistory = []
    redirect(URL('inandout'), 303)


def second():
    if request.vars.price:
        price = float(request.vars.price)
        # use the price to calculate profit and qsold
        currentprice, qsold, profit = session.marketobject.calculate_qsold_profit(price)
        # add the result to the history of prices, profits and qsold
        session.priceHistory.append(currentprice)
        session.profitHistory.append(profit)
        session.quantityHistory.append(qsold)
    redirect(URL('inandout'), 303)

def inandout():
    capacity = session.marketobject.K
    populationsize = session.marketobject.N
    mc = session.marketobject.MC
    maxWTP = session.marketobject.maxWTP    
    return dict(capacity=capacity, populationsize=populationsize,
                mc=mc, maxWTP=maxWTP, 
                priceHistory=session.priceHistory,
                profitHistory=session.profitHistory, 
                quantityHistory=session.quantityHistory)
```

**View: `inandout.html`**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>First page</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{=URL('static', 'css/testapp.css')}}">
</head>
<body>

  <h2>Seller capacity: {{=capacity}}</h2>
  <h2>Population size: {{=populationsize}}</h2>  
  <h2>MC: {{=mc}}</h2>
  <h2>Maximum WTP: {{=maxWTP}}</h2>

  <form action="second">
    Enter price: <input type="text" name="price">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

  <table>
      {{for count in range(len(priceHistory)):}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{=priceHistory[count]}}</td>
                <td>{{=quantityHistory[count]}}</td>
                <td>{{=profitHistory[count]}}</td>
            </tr>
      {{pass}} 
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**market, consumers and business modules**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8
import consumers
import business

class Market(object):

    def __init__(self, MC, maxWTP, N=30000, minWTP=0, 
                 FC=0, K=10000, numDecisions=3):
        self.numDecisions = numDecisions 
        self.K = K
        self.N = N
        self.MC = MC
        self.maxWTP = maxWTP

        self.consumerClass = consumers.AllConsumers(N, minWTP, maxWTP)
        self.seller = business.Seller(FC, MC, K)

    def calculate_qsold_profit(self, price):
        currentprice = price
        qtydemanded = self.consumerClass.qtyDemanded(currentprice)
        calculate_qsold_profit = \
                    self.seller.calculate_qsold_profit(currentprice,
                                                        qtydemanded)                                                   
        qSold = calculate_qsold_profit[0]
        profit = calculate_qsold_profit[1]

        return (currentprice, qSold,profit,)
```

**consumers.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8

import random

##=====================================================================
# Create the class that creates all consumers
##=====================================================================

class AllConsumers(object):

    def __init__(self, N, minWTP, maxWTP):
        self.N = N
        self.minWTP = minWTP
        self.maxWTP = maxWTP
        self.listOfWTPs = sorted([random.uniform(minWTP,maxWTP) \
                                        for x in range(N)], reverse=True)

    def qtyDemanded(self, price):
        count = 0
        for wtp in self.listOfWTPs:
                if wtp >= price:
                    count += 1
                else:
                    break
        return count
```

**business.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8

##=====================================================================
# Create a seller class 
##=====================================================================

class Seller(object):

    def __init__(self, FC, MC, K):
        self.FC = FC
        self.MC = MC
        self.K = K

    def calculate_qsold_profit(self, price, qtydemanded):
        # choose minimum of quantity demanded and capacity
        # create a vector of monthly capacity (same element repeated 12 times)
        qsold = min(qtydemanded,self.K)

        # Calculate the profit vector
        profit = ((price - self.MC) * qsold) - self.FC 

        return (qsold, profit)
```

Comment: Can we see the market module? You might also pack the whole application (or at least a minimal version that reproduces the problem) and post it on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).

Comment: @Anthony Thanks! I have added all the modules. Please let me know if you would still like me to package the app and post it on Google group. I am not sure, but it appears that the problem occurs in Chrome and not in other browsers (but I may be wrong since it does not happen everytime). To try and replicate it in Chrome, it may help to quickly enter the price and submit when the `inandout` page loads the first time. Thanks again.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in Chrome on Ubuntu or Windows 7, nor in IE on Windows 7. The only way I can reproduce the behavior is to first go to the index URL in one tab, then go to the index URL in a second tab, and then submit a price back in the first tab. In that case, the second visit to index causes new values of MC and maxWTP to be generated in the session, so when you submit a price in the first tab, the returned page has the newly generated MC and maxWTP values.

Comment: Note, all tabs within the same browser share the same session, so changes to session variables initiated by one tab will propagate to all other tabs.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony! I thought it might be hard to replicate. Well, I will use Safari for now since I have not had that problem in Safari.